# The function $g$ is continuous in discontinuity point

Tags: real-analysis, integration, stieltjes-integral

> Let $g \in V[a, b]$, where $V[a, b]$ is the set of functions of bounded variation on $[a,b]$. 
>   Show that existence of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_a^b f dg$ implies that $g$ is continuous in any discontinuity point of $f$.

May be I can show that the integral exist when $g$ is monotone increasing and continuous by substracting the upper and lower Riemann-Stieltjes sums and showing this quantity is smaller than any $\epsilon$?

Comment: Can we please, please use the actual terminology instead of "here are words that are somewhat similar to those in the problem, but I couldn't be bothered to actually say what it said"? For instance "total variation" is a function, not a set. One must presume you mean the set of functions of bounded variation. And what is "$\exists \int_a^b f dg$" supposed to mean?

Comment: So you are assuming that $g$ is of bounded variation.  Are you now asking how to prove that the existence of $\int_a^bf \, dg $ implies that $g$ is continuous wherever $f$ is discontinuous?

Comment: @PaulSinclair thank you for your answer. I apologize for this incorrect definition.

Comment: @RRL thank you for your answer. Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First prove (1) this is true if $g$ is a monotone increasing function and then (2) use the fact that any function of bounded variation is the difference of two increasing functions.

For (1) we show that if $g$ is not continuous at a point where $f$ is discontinuous, then the Riemann-Stieltjes integral cannot exist.

Suppose $g$ is monotone increasing and that WLOG $f$ and $g$ are discontinuous from the right at $\xi \in (a,b).$  Consider any partition $P = (x_0,x_1, \ldots, x_{i-1},\xi, x_i, \ldots, x_n)$ with $\xi$ as a partition point and $x_i - \xi = \delta_i$

There exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $\delta > 0$ (including $\delta_i$), there are points $y_1, y_2 \in (\xi, \xi + \delta)$ such that $|f(y_1) - f(\xi)| \geqslant \epsilon$ and  $|g(y_2) - g(\xi)| \geqslant \epsilon$.

Then we have

$$U(P,f,g) - L(P,f,g) \geqslant \epsilon^2,$$

since $g(x_i) - g(\xi) \geqslant g(y_2) - g(\xi) \geqslant \epsilon$ and $\sup_{x \in [\xi,x_i]} f(x) - \inf_{x \in [\xi,x_i]}  f(x) \geqslant \epsilon$

Therefore, the Riemann criterion is not satisfied and $f$ is not RS integrable with respect to $g$ on $[a,b]$.

I'll let you consider part (2).

Comment: thank you for your answer! Could you explain definitions of $U$ and $L$ in $U(P, f, g) - L(P, f, g)$? What is the purpose of this inequality?

Comment: Upper and lower Riemann-Stieltjes sums.  The Riemann criterion for integrability states that $\int_a^bf\, dg$ exists if and only if for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists a partition $P$ of the interval such that $U(P,f,g) - L(P,f,g) < \epsilon$. The answer proves that the integral does not exist when $f$ and $g$ share a common discontinuity by showing the Riemann criterion does not hold.  You need to know these basic concepts of integration before you can tackle a difficult problem like this.