# Bounded function and integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, education

Sorry if my English isn't good I'm from Croatia.

Offer an example of function bounded g and a non-decreasing function $\beta$ defined in $[a,b]$ such that $\mid g\mid \in R(\beta)$ but for which $\int_a^b g d\beta$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Don't you mean $\int_a^b g \, d\beta$ doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If $g$ and $\beta $ are discontinuous at the same point, the Riemann-Stieltjes integral does not exist.  See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2534873/148510).

Take

$$g(x) = \begin{cases}-1, & 0 \leqslant x < 1/2\\ 1, & 1/2 \leqslant x \leqslant 1 \end{cases}$$

and find a suitable $\beta$ to finish.